# Running Apache Spark latest version of the cluster with the older version

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-spark

I have Cloudera CDH 5.2.2 cluster with Apache Spark 1.5.0.

Is there any way to run on this cluster application using Apache Spark 2.0 with Dataset API? Сluster settings is desirable do not change.

I tried using maven-shade-plugin run the built-in to JAR Spark 2.0.0, but it does not work (NoSuchMethodException).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `Spark` 2.0.0 features, your cluster should be running `Spark` 2.0.0. I don't think there is a workaround for this. Exceptions like `NoSuchMethodExeception` are thrown because the methods or signatures of the methods you are using have changed from 1.5.0 to 2.0.0 and therefore the cluster does not understand them.